# Reading part of dataset stored i HDF5 - python 2.7

Tags: python, split, dataset, hdf5, dataframe

I have a rather large HDF5 file which stores (among other things) a large time series dataset with eyetracking data on 150 participants.

```
In [20]: f['data_collection/events/eyetracker/BinocularEyeSampleEvent/']
Out[21]: <HDF5 dataset "BinocularEyeSampleEvent": shape (8297323,), type "|V178">
```

I cannot read all of this into memory because it is to large, but how can I read in part of it?

I would like to do something like this - read one participant at the time (columnname for participants is "name"), perform some operations and save to a smaller dataframe:

```
for name in f['data_collection/events/eyetracker/BinocularEyeSampleEvent/'][name]:
    df = f['data_collection/events/eyetracker/BinocularEyeSampleEvent/']
    ...
    ...
```

How can I do this? I am using the h5py for reading the HDF5 file.

/Martin

Answer (score 0):

Your problem looks like a Map Reduce algorithm. Since you got huge dataset, you should convert your data into a map reduce algorithm which outputs key,value pairs of data you are concerned with on a hadoop cluster. This way you can handle a lot of data. Check this link for help:

http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/writing-an-hadoop-mapreduce-program-in-python/

Hadoop uses HDFS too so it might help you. A Mapper only manipulates data that you are concerned with and outputs key, value and reducer does some aggregation.